# Undefined element that actually is defined

Tags: typescript

I have an Object that is being called into async:

```
async setCurrentCompany(Company: CompanyModel){
  this.currentCompany = Company;
  this.teams = Company.teams as Array<TeamDataModel>;
  console.log(this.currentCompany);
  console.log(Company.teams);
}
```

The next Object is equals to Company

```
{Name: "HelloWorld",
teams: [{ Name: "HelloWorld"}]
}
```

When I make a console.log(SomeConst.ExtraNames) or I'll try to put the value into another constant it throws me undefined, but it exists, Why this happens?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in the code you've provided, so you shouldn't even be able to get that far in the first place. Can you show your actual code? My guess is you're setting it asynchronously or there's a scope issue or something like that because (if the syntax errors are fixed) what you've shown should work fine.

Comment: Remove the : object and let typescript infer a more specific type for your object.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I added the code, the object is a summarize of the real object, it is so large

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I added the code, the object is a summarize of the real object, it is so large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something strange with naming. In TS/JS we don't have `Const` we have `const`.

you should change your code to look like this

```
const someConst = {
 name: "HelloWorld",
 extraNames: [{ name: "HelloWorld" }],
};
```

the reason why you gen `undefined` is because you've declared type of `someConst` as `object`. If you remove it as I show you in the example above TS should type infer that you have property `extraNames`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a comma missing, try this:

```
{Name: "HelloWorld",
ExtraNames: [{ Name: "HelloWorld"}]
}
```